# Catch the status of a checkbox using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have config file. 
**config.json**

```
{
"checkFlag":"1"
}
```

which I read using nodejs, to set the initial value of a **checkBox**  and serve a webpage as follows:

**app.js**

```
    const  express = require('express')
const app = express()
var path =require('path')
var fs = require('fs')
var os = require( 'os' );
var config_fileName = './public/scripts/config.json';
const router =    express.Router();
var configFile = require(config_fileName);
app.use(express.static('public'))
var ejs = require('ejs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(config_fileName);
let checkflag = JSON.parse(rawdata);
console.log(checkflag.checkFlag);

// Serving index.html
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.get('/', (req,res,next) => {
    res.render('index', {
        checkvalue:"checked"});

     res.end();

});



app.post('/check',(req,res)=>{

    console.log('check')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

and the html code is the following:

```
**index.ejs**


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>check Box</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <p> hey</p>
    <form action="/check" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="example" <%=checkvalue%>>reading flag  <%=checkvalue%> <br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The reading works fine, but I need to rewrite the config file is the box is checked/unchecked, for that I've tried using a form but apparently, it isn't working. any Idea how may I do this using NodeJS ?

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading you can directly do this

```
var config = require(config_fileName);
```

require parses the config.json and returns an object. So for accessing `checkFlag`, you can just do `config.checkFlag`

In your HTML you need a submit button

```html
<form action="/check" method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="example" <%=checkvalue%>>reading flag  <%=checkvalue%> <br>
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And in your app.js, you need to have a handler for this request

```
app.post('/check',(req,res) => {
    config.checkFlag = req.body.example;
    fs.writeFileSync(config_fileName, JSON.stringify(config)); 
});
```